# livereload fired but does not reload page when changes are generated by contrib-copy or tinyimg in destination (!)

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

Here is my problem.

All mentioned paths as per below gruntfile.js are watched fine (shown in grunt --verbose -v). Livereload fires whenever I change files (at least --verbose shows livereload fires). But the page is live reloaded ONLY in case I change my /development/index.html (in Sublime Text) or /less/mainpage.less (with contrib-less).

If I change development/img/**/* or anyting in /test/**/*, livereload FIRES but do not RELOAD my page.

I would really appreciate if someone could help.

Here is my folder structure:

[source location root: /development/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAtSJ.png)

[destination location root: /test/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI5Ok.png)

Here is my gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({

watch: {
    livereload: {
        files: ['development/*.html', "test/**/*", "development/img/**/*"],
        options: {
            livereload: true,
            spawn: false
        }
    },

    // watch tasks start here
    scripts: {
        files: ['development/js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['concat']
    },
    html: {
        files: ['development/*.html'],
        tasks: ['copy:html']
    },
    less_compile: {
        files: ['development/a_source/less/**/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less', "stripCssComments"]
    },
    images: {
        files: ['development/img/**/*'],
        tasks: ['tinyimg']
    }
},

// runs local server for livereload
connect: {
    sever: {
        options: {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            base: 'test/',
            livereload: true
        }
    }
},

// *** *.html, *.img copy task here
copy: {
    html: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'development',
        src: '*.html',
        dest: 'test/',
    }
},

// *** LESS tasks here
less: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            paths: ["development/b_components/less/"]
        },
        files: {
            "temp/css/style.css": "development/a_source/less/style.less"
        }
    }
}, // compiles less and put compiled version into /temp/css/style.test

stripCssComments: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'test/css/style.css': 'temp/css/style.css'
        }
    }
}, // strips comments from /temp/css/style.css and copies it to /test/

// minify images
tinyimg: {
    dynamic: {
        files: [{
            expand: true, // Enable dynamic expansion
            cwd: 'development/img/', // Src matches are relative to this path
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'], // Actual patterns to match
            dest: 'test/img/' // Destination path prefix
        }]
    }
}

}); //initConfig

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-strip-css-comments');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-tinyimg');

grunt.registerTask('default', ["connect", "watch"]);

}; //wrapper function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
livereload:{
    options:{
      livereload:'<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files:[
      'app/{,*/}*.html',
      'app/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
```

This should reload if you make changes in your images folder. (Customize the URL according to your structure.)

Comment: Sorry, struggling with the comment editing :) 
Thank you @Guarav_soni. Well I tested. It works partially after I changed files paths in the template you gave the following way:    files: ['test/img/*.jpg', 'test/{,*/}*.html', 'test/css/*.css', 'test/js/*.js']. Partially means images livereload did not work anyway. Watch and tinyimg work fine, livereload fires for all changes at test/img/*.jpg and shows the files coped to localhost. But the page does not reload in case of /test/img/*.jpg changes.

Comment: Checked with Chrome Dev Tools and Firefox inspector. If I check the pic preview in network tab after reload fired in grunt watching, the picture is not updated. If I load the picture from localhost:3000/img/img1.jpg it shows the correct version.

Comment: At last I found npm live-server (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q78u9lBXvj0), https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server and it worked just within minutes. I left grunt to manage only watch my source to run compile/copy/concat etc. And I let live-server watch changes in destination and reload the page. No configs for it. Magic :)

Comment: I had tried the recipes here: [link]https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/362, but with no result. Still very interested why changing *.html, *.css, *.js in destination did fired page updates, but images did not.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I just wanted to wrap up after I solved all my problems.

I arrived at the following acceptably working setup:
 - as per above: Grunt serves as only "files" worker doing all compile / concat / copy etc.
   work.
   - browser-sync is my local server (with bunch of other vital capabilities) and fast livereload tool, that additionally syncs
   several open test windows (https://browsersync.io/).
   - Divvy: great addition to my workflow capable of arranging windows on the desktop on the fly (http://mizage.com/divvy/).

Comment: Hey @bob-12345 , good to know u solved the problem. Check out grunt-contrib-connect. I prefer this over browsersync , as it keeps the tools unified.

Comment: Hello @Guarav_soni. I have tried with grunt-contrib-connect for totally about pure 24 hours, not in a row though :) just because of unification sake. Could not make it work. I made it easy though with both. instead of 1 open terminal window I have two) Not much work to open 2 terminals and start 2 files once a day, compared to the benefits))

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Soon after I switched to Gulp + Browsersync. I could not be satisfied more. Gulp works roughly 10 times faster and Browsersync is smooth and convenient.

Here is my gulpfile.js example just to demonstrate the tasks this pair manages for me:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    gutil = require("gulp-util"),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    gulpcopy = require('gulp-copy'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglifyjs = require('gulp-uglify'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    htmlhint = require("gulp-htmlhint"),
    htmlv = require('gulp-html-validator'),
    validatecss = require('gulp-w3c-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var lessMain = ["src/styles/less/styles.less"],
    lessSources = ["src/styles/less/*.less", "src/styles/**/*.css"],
    jsSources = "src/js/*.js",
    jsonSources = ["src/js/*.json"],
    htmlSources = ["src/html/*.html"],
    imgSources = ["z_design/images/processed/**/*.*"],
    imgDest = ["public/img/**/*.*"],
    cssTemp = ["src/temp/css/styles.css"],
    srcjQuery = "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    srcMustache = "node_modules/mustache/mustache.min.js";

gulp.task("message", function() {
    gutil.log("============= Gulp script started ==============");
});

// compiling less
gulp.task("less-compile", function() {
    gulp.src(lessMain)
        // switches sourcemaps on/off
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())

        .pipe(less()
            .on("error", gutil.log))

        // switches sourcemaps on/off
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())

        // change .dest("folder") to "public/css"
        // to make no-autoprefix
        // or to "src/temp/css/" to switch autoprefix on
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/css"))
});

// prepare & copy js files
gulp.task("js", function() {
    gulp.src([srcjQuery, srcMustache, jsSources])
        .pipe(concat("script.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/js/"))
});

// .pipe(browserify())
// {bundleExternal: false}

// copy JSON files
gulp.task("copyjson", function() {
    gulp.src(jsonSources)
        .pipe(newer("public/js/"))
        .pipe(gulpcopy("public/js/", {
            prefix: 2
        }))
});

// copy html files
gulp.task("copyhtml", function() {
    gulp.src(htmlSources)
        .pipe(newer("public/"))
        .pipe(gulpcopy("public/", {
            prefix: 2
        }))
});


// --- minify & compress images: 2 tasks - auto and manual

// minify & copy images - manual task
gulp.task("img-ondemand", function() {
    gulp.src("z_design/images/unprocessed/**/*.*")
        .pipe(newer("public/img/"))
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('z_design/images/processed/'))
});

// minify & copy images - automatic task
gulp.task("processimages", function() {
    gulp.src(imgSources)
        .pipe(newer("public/img/"))
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/img/'))
});
// --- end

// forced reload
gulp.task("reload", function() {
    browserSync.reload();
});

// autoprefixer
gulp.task("autoprefix", function() {
    gulp.src(cssTemp)
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'ie 10', "ie11", 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public/css/"))
});

// watching for changes
gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch(lessSources, ["less-compile"])
    gulp.watch(jsSources, ["js"])
    gulp.watch(jsonSources, ["copyjson"])
    gulp.watch(htmlSources, ["copyhtml"])
    gulp.watch(imgSources, ["processimages"])
    gulp.watch(imgDest, ["reload"])
    gulp.watch("src/temp/css/styles.css", ["autoprefix"])
});

// serving localhost
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: ["public", "src"],
        watchTask: true,
        open: false,
        files: ["public/*.html", "public/css/*.css", "public/js/*.*",
            "public/img/**/*.*"]
    });
});

// === production preparations: RUN SEPARATE TASKS ON DEMAND ===

// --- minify & compress HTML, CSS, JS

// uglify JS
gulp.task("compress-js", function() {
    gulp.src("public/js/script.js")
        .pipe(uglifyjs())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
});

// uglify CSS
gulp.task('uglify-css', function() {
    gulp.src('public/css/styles.css')
        .pipe(uglifycss({
            "debug": true,
            "uglyComments": true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
});

// compress HTML
gulp.task('compress-html', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/html/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});


// --- lint HTML and validate CSS

// lint html
gulp.task('lint-html', function() {
    gulp.src("public/*.html")
        .pipe(htmlhint())
        .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
});

// validate html
// Option format set to html 
gulp.task('validate-html', function() {
    gulp.src('public/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlv({
            format: 'html'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/temp/validation/'));
});

// add css validation
gulp.task('validate-css', function() {
    gulp.src('public/css/*.css')
        .pipe(validatecss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/temp/validation/'));
});


gulp.task("validate", ["validate-html", "validate-css", "lint-html"]);

gulp.task("compress", ["compress-js", "uglify-css", "compress-html"]);

gulp.task("default", ["watch", "browser-sync"]);

// =======================
```